# Self adjointness of square root operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Theorem:
If $A$ is self adjoint and nonnegative, then $A$ has a unique nonnegative square root $A^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

As I understand, thesis of this theorem say only about the existence of $A^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

When is it true, that $A^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is self adjoint? (on what additional assumptions needed)

Comment: It is always true. In fact, self-adjointnes is part of the definition of "nonnegative".

Comment: I agree with you but only in bounded case (Operator $A$ is bounded). I'm still not sure, what is in unbounded case?

Comment: @ela Have you some reference of this theorem?

Comment: @Etienne Not quite. You can derive self-adjoint from the definition of non-negative operator. i.e. all non-negative operators are self-adjoint.

Answer (score 4):

It goes like this:

If $A$ is a non-negative self-adjoint matrix, then by the Spectral Theorem, we have

$$ A = UDU^{*}$$

where $U$ is a unitary matrix and $D$ is the diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues of $A$ as the diagonal entries. Since $A$ is non-negative these eigenvalues are also non-negative.

Now let $ E = \sqrt{D}$ be the diagonal matrix with each diagonal entry being the square root of the corresponding diagonal entry in $D$ (possible as diagonal entries of $D$ are non-negative).

Now clearly,

$$ (UEU^{*}) ^{2} = A $$

whence $\sqrt{A} = UEU^{*}$ which by the spectral theorem again is self-adjoint and non-negative.

Please note that non-negative matrix is a self-adjoint matrix such that $\langle x,Ax \rangle \geq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. So a non-negative matrix is always self-adjoint, by definition.

Comment: You consider that $A$ is a matrix. Is it still true for unbounded operator $A$?

Comment: Yes it is true for unbounded non-negative self-adjoint operator $A$ as well (Here non-negative means the spectrum of $A$ is a subset of positive reals). The idea is again to use functional calculus.

Comment: @ela Do you know functional calculus for unbounded self-adjoint operators?

Comment: I found proof in T. Kato "Pertutbation theory of linear operators", but I have to analyze it. It seems that one more assumption is needed.

Comment: What assumption?

Comment: Theorem 3.35. Let T be m-accretive. Then there is a unique m-accretive
square soot $T^{\frac{1}{2}}$ o f T such that $(T^{\frac{1}{2}})^{2} = T$. $T^{\frac{1}{2}}$ has the following additional
properties.
iv) If T is selfadjoint and nonnegative, $T^{\frac{1}{2}}$ has the same properties.

Comment: So what is the additional assumption?

Comment: m-accertive is from definition: $(A+\lambda)^{-1}\in B(H)$ and $\Vert (A+\lambda)^{-1} \Vert <=(Re(\lambda))^{-1}$ for $Re(\lambda)>0$.

Comment: The result is also true for self adjoint operators.

Comment: Is m-acceretive more general assumption?

Comment: I will post a detailed answer tomorrow.

Comment: I am sorry. I got a little busy with things lately. You could look at "Unbounded Self-Adjoint Operators on Hilbert Spaces" by Konrad Schmudgen, Springer for details. Specifically, see Chapter 5.